# Extract dates and calculate difference

Tags: powershell, datetime

I have two different objects.
One would be an WMI Event Log and the other a WMI Management object.

How would I extract the dates from these variable and find a time difference?

Edit:

```
$start = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "commandline like '%something%'" -ComputerName $server | %{ $_.ConvertToDateTime($_.CreationDate) }
$end = Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $server -Query "SELECT TimeGenerated FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE LogFile='Application' AND CategoryString = 'Server Startup'" | Select  TimeGenerated -First 1
```

Sample output of the two:

```
1/20/2016 3:55:48 PM
@{TimeGenerated=20160120210057.000000-000}
```

It is necessary to use the -Query for the end time, as the event is distinguished by the Category.
I'm currently getting the following error when trying to subtract the two.

```
Cannot find an overload for "op_Subtraction" and the argument count: "2".
```

Comment: Use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter: `| Select -ExpandProperty TimeGenerated -First 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the subtraction operator (`-`):

```
$diff = $end.'Eventlog Time: ' - $start.'ABCD Start Time'
```

Or pass the values as arguments to `New-TimeSpan`:

```
$diff = New-TimeSpan -Start $start.'ABCD Start Time' -End $end.'Eventlog Time: '
```

---

It seems like you attempt to "optimize" the property names for displaying it later - I would recommend against that, and simply store the `DateTime` object in the variable by itself:

```
$start = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "commandline like '%something%'" -ComputerName $server | Select -First 1 |%{ $_.ConvertToDateTime($_.CreationDate) }
$end = Get-EventLog System -Newest 1 -ComputerName $server -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon |Select -ExpandProperty TimeGenerated

$diff = $end - $start
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the refactoring, I've changed it to be so.
I'm getting an error on the End time:

`{ $_.ConvertToDateTime($_.TimeGenerated) }`

Saying the ConvertToDateTime does not exist.

Comment: @StephenSugumar Sorry, overlooked that. You don't need to convert it, `$_.TimeGenerated` *is* already of the type `DateTime`